# Is there any downsides to running ros as root in Docker?

Tags: docker, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normally outside of docker we are running a non-root machine and just sudo everything.
Docker is doing every thing in root, does that cause any issues?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344195/is-there-any-downsides-to-running-ros-as-root-in-docker?/) by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as ROS functionality itself I have never experienced any issues running inside of Docker as a root user since I started using Docker with ROS four years ago.

In order to access devices, network and other resources on the host machine you need to understand how Docker does it in general and you will be fine

---

Originally posted by [viktor.holova](https://answers.ros.org/users/51651/viktor.holova/) with karma: 201 on 2020-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0